# Visual Studio Express 2013 wont start after new installation

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Im working on Windows 8.1 OS and today i downloaded Visual Studio Express 2013 from [here](https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/profile/review?download=true&family=VisualStudioExpressDesktop&release=VisualStudio2013Upd4&type=web&slcid=0x407&mkt=de-DE&context=eyJwZSI6MSwicGMiOjEsImljIjoxLCJhbyI6MCwiYW0iOjAsIm9wIjpudWxsLCJhZCI6MSwiZmEiOjAsImF1IjpudWxsLCJjdiI6MTgzNDUwMDEwNiwiZnMiOjAsInN1IjowLCJlciI6MX01).
The installation took round about 20 minutes. After it was installed i pressed the launch 
button but nothing happended. So i pressed Windows + q and searched for `Express 2013`. The 
computer found the correct programm. i pressed on the icon to start it and got an error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Micorosoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\VSWinExpress.exe

The application has failed to start because the side-by-side configuration is incorrect. 
Please see the application event log for more details.
```

I tried to figure out what the problem is but i didnt get it running. i tried to repair the installation, i tried a restart, i tried to deinstall everything, restart and install it again.
I cant start it, always that error message.

It was a clean new installation.... how can that even be...

EDIT:

From the Event-Log i found out that the system cant find `debuggerproxy.dll`. Where can 
i get it and where does it have to be and why does a new installation of visual studio express 2013 does not deliver this dll?

Comment: Visual Studio 12.0 = VS 2013; VS 2012 is Visual Studio 11.0 ....

Comment: Yes... and how should that help me? My question is still the same and the title is correct.